# read csv file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv

I use this code in vb.net for reading in csv files:

```
filename = TextBox1.Text
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input)

        'first row contains header information, therefore read it in, but ignore it
        dummy = LineInput(1)

        While Not EOF(1)

            Input(1, dialcode)
            Input(1, chargecode)
            Input(1, description)
            Input(1, mincharge)
            Input(1, onpeak)
            Input(1, offpeak)
            Input(1, weekendonpeak)
            Input(1, weekendoffpeak)
            Input(1, onpeakconnect)
            Input(1, offpeakconnect)
            Input(1, weekendonpeakconnect)
            Input(1, weekendoffpeakconnect)
End While
```

this work fine

but i now have a different CSV to read in, and it has a , at the end of each line when i open the CSV file in notepad, so its not reading each row in because vb.net is unsure when a row ends

Comment: You "use this code" or did you "write this code"?

Comment: wrote it and use it (:

Comment: Why don't you just read and discard the rest of the line?

Answer (score 23):

.Net has a built in CSV reader in the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx).  It will handle things like extra commas or quoted delimiters for you. For example, you could do this:

```
Dim dialcode As String
Dim chargecode As String
Dim mincharge As String

Dim tfp As New TextFieldParser("Z:\temp\test.csv")
tfp.Delimiters = New String() {","}
tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited


tfp.ReadLine() ' skip header
While tfp.EndOfData = False
    Dim fields = tfp.ReadFields()
    dialcode = fields(0)
    chargecode = fields(1)
    mincharge = fields(2)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", dialcode, chargecode, mincharge))
End While
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub ParseCSV(ByVal path As String)
    Dim inidex As Integer
    Dim oxygenSaturation As Object
    Dim pulse As Object

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
    TextFieldParser(path)

        MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}

        MyReader.ReadLine() ' skip header
        'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
        'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                'currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim fields = MyReader.ReadFields()

                inidex = fields(0)
                oxygenSaturation = fields(28)
                pulse = fields(30)

                Dim a As String
                a = "Index = " & inidex & "oxygenSaturation = " & oxygenSaturation & "pulse = " & pulse
                MessageBox.Show(a, "Has been Changed", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)

                ' Include code here to handle the row.
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```