# Text Quilifier In CSV File VB.NET

Tags: string, csv, text, split

I am trying split a csv file into columns and the file contains a text qualifier for address but the address is split by comma inside the " ".

I need to be able to read the text qualifier and ignore the comma until the end of the text qualifier. Not all columns have text qualifier.

I have managed to separate the rows into correct format (amount of columns) and wrong format (too many columns) but I can not think of how I would approach this!

Any suggestions or articles?

```
Dim path As String = txb_FileName.Text
    Dim tbl = New DataTable
    Dim Btbl = New DataTable
    
    'OpenFile
    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)

    'Check If First Line is in correcct format
    Dim colCount = lines.First.Split(","c).Length
    Dim rowCount = lines.Count

    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_1"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_2"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_3"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_4"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_5"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_6"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_7"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_8"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_9"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_10"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_11"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_12"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_13"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_14"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_15"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_16"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_17"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_18"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_19"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_20"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_21"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_22"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_23"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_24"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_25"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_26"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_27"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_28"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_29"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_30"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_31"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_32"))
    tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_33"))




    For Each line In lines

        Dim colCount1 = lines.First.Split(","c).Length

        Dim objFields = From field In line.Split(","c)
                        Select field
        If line.Split(","c).Count > 33 Then

                Dim BnewRow = Btbl.Rows.Add()
                BnewRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()

            Else
                Dim newRow = tbl.Rows.Add()
                newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()

            End If
        ' End If

    Next

    Dim dgv1 As New DataGridView

    dgv1.DataSource = tbl

    Me.Controls.Add(dgv1)
```

Data:

```
66641515,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-15,9090-11-16,KEKHTGpG,PREETD,4147399967,1999-05-95,pE46NR,"",94,FEMGpE,peimeKken,"",E01013696,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,PnkKidi@gmail.mom,+447754601754,"",FGpKE,knue,4147399967,"","","64 Genmfn Kkneek, peimeKken, pE4 6NR","",07594453519,"",C49044,100.00,1
66434471,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-17,TDpKDNKpN,EMMG,4904714506,1943-09-15,DN394PG,"",37,FEMGpE,Nonkh EaKk pinmolnKhine,"",E01013160,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,ega_537@hokmail.mom,+447775070709,01479317194,FGpKE,knue,4904714506,"","","1a Beamon Counk, GnimKbf, Koukh HumbenKide, DN39 4PG","",07775070709,01479310546,B41655,100.00,1
66417599,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-17,pppLD,GGNE,4964994134,1967-19-19,CM41PT,"",59,FEMGpE,EKKex,"",E01091493,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,"",+447790990963,"",FGpKE,knue,4964994134,"","","17 Glan Road, Tikham, EKKex, CM4 1PT","",07790990963,"",F41030,100.00,1
66694443,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-15,9090-11-17,CppE,BGRBGRG,4344635399,1930-09-14,pK951HG,"",90,FEMGpE,peedK,"",E01011403,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,auguKkuK.mounk@hm-one.mo.uk,"","",TRGE,knue,4344635399,"","","GuguKkuK Counk Cane Home, Chunmh GandenK, Ganfonkh, pEEDK, TeKk LonkKhine, pK95 1HG","","",01133450000,B46044,100.00,1
66656193,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-16,KGNDHER,GGRVDNDER,4366119969,1975-04-30,GB44EZ,"",45,MGpE,Hillingdon,"",E01009493,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,m19guv@hokmail.mom,+447416415995,09045491079,FGpKE,knue,4366119969,"","","44 Meadow View Road, HafeK, MiddleKex, GB4 4EZ","",07416415995,"",E45191,100.00,1
66764369,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-17,EPPK,ZENG,4366466635,1971-01-97,MK164RF,"",49,FEMGpE,Milkon KefneK,"",E01016749,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,z.eppK@bkinkennek.mom,+447944047447,"",FGpKE,knue,4366466635,"","","41 pGTRENCE TGpK, NETPpRT PGGNEpp, BGCKK, MK16 4RF",z.eppK@bkinkennek.mom,07944047447,07944047447,K49074,100.00,1
66651739,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-16,MGRTDN,NDCHppGK,4349444339,1975-11-13,KT49pH,"",45,MGpE,Kunnef,"",E01030335,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,Nimk.Kmankin@fewo.mom,+447914519619,"",FGpKE,knue,4349444339,"","","4 DKland Fanm Road, TeKk MoleKef, Kunnef, KT4 9pH","",07914519619,09044730669,H41074,100.00,1
66400539,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-17,MDppK,EMMG,4346996744,1945-11-96,KE979RX,"",34,FEMGpE,pambekh,"",E01003065,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,egamillK040@gmail.mom,+447439790559,"",FGpKE,knue,4346996744,"","","Flak 10 pilian Rolfe HouKe, VinmenneK EKkake Hamilkon Road, ppNDpN, KE97 9RX","",07439790559,"",G45199,100.00,1
66657901,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-16,CpKTEppp,BEN,4490006945,1946-11-19,KK131NG,"",34,MGpE,EKKex,"",E01091304,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,"",+447494144506,"",FGpKE,knue,4490006945,"","","90 Kkokefelde, PikKea, BGKDpDpN, EKKex, KK13 1NG","",07990949067,01964554677,F41031,100.00,1
66737591,KGRK-KdZ-1 CpRpNGVDRGK ,9090-11-16,9090-11-17,CpRDDNGpEL,DRENE,4499914179,1944-11-91,TG149GB,"",75,FEMGpE,Tnaffond,"",E01006075,P,440,PDppGR 9 TEKTDNG,inene.mondinglef@Kkf.mom,+447945357514,01613076500,FGpKE,knue,4499914179,"","","91 The PoplanK, NonmanK Plame, GpTRDNCHGM, CheKhine, TG14 9GB",inene.mondinglef@Kkf.mom,07945357514,01619076500,P91004,100.00,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) for that.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791786/read-csv-file-in-vb-net) for an extra example.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
TextFieldParser("C:\20201118025447904026_DE279D.csv")

        MyReader.TextFieldType =
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Dim currentRow As String()

        MyReader.CommentTokens = New String() {""}
        MyReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

        'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
        'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                ' Include code here to handle the row.
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
```