# How do I insert data from a text file into a 2D Array in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Currently I have these data inside my textfile.txt:

[image: data in txtfile]

I want to split them up into a 2D array when a comma is met. How do I do so?

This is my code for now. Please do point out the mistakes I made.

```
Dim priceArray(5, 2) As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim data As String
Dim oilpriceFile As System.IO.StreamReader 
oilpriceFile = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\zack\OneDrive\Desktop\oilprice.txt")
        
For i = 0 To UBound(priceArray)
      data = oilpriceFile.ReadLine()
      For j = 0 To UBound(priceArray)
          priceArray(i, j) = data.Split(",") //there's an error stating "value of type string() cannot be converted into string"
          j = j + 1
      Next
      i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service nor a tutorial site. If you want to do something, you need to put the effort in to learn how and do it. If what you try doesn't work as expected, THEN you have a question to ask here. You can then explain what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try. As with all programming problems, break it down into the smallest parts possible and address each one individually. Can you read CSV data? If not then the array is irrelevant, so address that part first. Etc.

Comment: The error message your getting tells you exactly what’s wrong.  The Split function returns an array of string which your trying to assign to a single string variable.  Turn on Option Strict for your project and issue like this will be instantly visible

Comment: If your data is in csv fornat, use a csv reader. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791786/read-csv-file-in-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you are doing incorrectly.

First turn on Option Strict in the Project Properties and also under Options on the Tools menu.

You do not declare the increment variables used in `For` loops.

`StreanReader` needs to be disposed. You should know this because you always check the documentation before you use an unfamiliar framework class. When you do this you will see a `Dispose` method. When you see this, it needs to be called when you are through with using it. See `Using...End Using`.

You don't have to deal with `Dispose` if you use `File.ReadAllLines()`. This returns an array of the lines in the file.

A `For` loop increments the value of the first variable automatically. You do not increment it explicitly or you will skip values.

You have defined a 2 dimensional array. When you call `UBound` on the array, which dimension are you calling it on?? You must indicate which dimension you are asking about.

`UBound(priceArray, 1)` and `UBound(priceArray, 2)`

Where 1 and 2 designate the dimension you are getting.

This is the old vb6 way to get this value. The .net framework provides `GetUpperBound()` for the same purpose. This method uses the .net zero based rank where `GetUpperBound(0)` will return upper bound of  the first dimension of the array.

The next problem is the use of `Spilt`. `Split` returns an array of strings and you are trying to assign it to a single string. It takes a `Char` as a parameter. You have passed a `String`. To tell the compiler that you intend a `Char` follow the `String` by a lower case `c`.

A side note. `//` is the comment indicator in C#. In vb.net use the single quote `'`.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim priceArray(5, 2) As String
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\zack\OneDrive\Desktop\oilprice.txt")
    For i = 0 To priceArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim data = lines(i)
        Dim splits = data.Split(","c)
        For j = 0 To priceArray.GetUpperBound(1)
            priceArray(i, j) = splits(j)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```